# Send client requests to broker only when a worker is available and broker is available

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

With **`ZeroMQ`** for distributed messaging, I'm using the example code provided for the paranoid pirate pattern in python.  I have a single **client** (potentially may have more clients) a **broker** and multiple **workers**.

I have modified the example such that the client will continue to send requests to the broker queue even when no workers are available rather than retrying and eventually exiting.  They will get distributed to the worker(s) when they eventually become available.  In my scenario each worker varies in the amount of time it takes to process a given request.

The problem I'm seeing is that when the broker goes down (becomes unavailable), the client is unable to tell that the broker is unavailable and it continues to **`.send()`** requests. These requests get lost.  Only new requests are processed after the broker becomes available once again.

**`Client.py`**

```
from random import randint
import time

import zmq

HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS = 3
HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 1
INTERVAL_INIT = 1
INTERVAL_MAX = 32

#  Paranoid Pirate Protocol constants
PPP_READY = "PPP_READY"      # Signals worker is ready
PPP_HEARTBEAT = "PPP_HEARTBEAT"  # Signals worker heartbeat

def worker_socket(context, poller):
    """Helper function that returns a new configured socket
       connected to the Paranoid Pirate queue"""
    worker = context.socket(zmq.DEALER) # DEALER
    identity = "%04X-%04X" % (randint(0, 0x10000), randint(0, 0x10000))
    worker.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, identity)
    poller.register(worker, zmq.POLLIN)
    worker.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")
    worker.send(PPP_READY)
    return worker

context = zmq.Context(1)
poller = zmq.Poller()

liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
interval = INTERVAL_INIT

heartbeat_at = time.time() + HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL

worker = worker_socket(context, poller)
cycles = 0
while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL * 1000))

    # Handle worker activity on backend
    if socks.get(worker) == zmq.POLLIN:
        #  Get message
        #  - 3-part envelope + content -> request
        #  - 1-part HEARTBEAT -> heartbeat
        frames = worker.recv_multipart()
        if not frames:
            break # Interrupted

        if len(frames) == 3:
            print "I: Normal reply: ", frames
            liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
            time.sleep(4)  # Do some heavy work
            worker.send_multipart(frames)
        elif len(frames) == 1 and frames[0] == PPP_HEARTBEAT:
           # print "I: Queue heartbeat"
            liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
        else:
            print "E: Invalid message: %s" % frames
        interval = INTERVAL_INIT
    else:
        liveness -= 1
        if liveness == 0:
            print "W: Heartbeat failure, can't reach queue"
            print ("W: Reconnecting in")
            time.sleep(interval)

            if interval < INTERVAL_MAX:
                interval *= 2
            poller.unregister(worker)
            worker.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
            worker.close()
            worker = worker_socket(context, poller)
            liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
    if time.time() > heartbeat_at:
        heartbeat_at = time.time() + HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL
        #print "I: Worker heartbeat"
        worker.send(PPP_HEARTBEAT)
```

**`Broker.py`**

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import time
import threading
import zmq

HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS = 3     # 3..5 is reasonable
HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 1.0   # Seconds

#  Paranoid Pirate Protocol constants
PPP_READY = "PPP_READY"      # Signals worker is ready
PPP_HEARTBEAT = "PPP_HEARTBEAT"  # Signals worker heartbeat
PPP_BUSY = "PPP_BUSY"
PPP_FREE = "PPP_FREE"

class Worker(object):
    def __init__(self, address):
        self.address = address
        self.expiry = time.time() + HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL * HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS

class WorkerQueue(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.queue = OrderedDict()

    def ready(self, worker):
        self.queue.pop(worker.address, None)
        self.queue[worker.address] = worker

    def purge(self):
        """Look for & kill expired workers."""
        t = time.time()
        expired = []
        for address,worker in self.queue.iteritems():
            if t > worker.expiry:  # Worker expired
                expired.append(address)
        for address in expired:
            print "W: Idle worker expired: %s" % address
            self.queue.pop(address, None)

    def next(self):
        address, worker = self.queue.popitem(False)
        return address

context = zmq.Context(1)
clcontext = zmq.Context()

frontend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER) # ROUTER
backend = context.socket(zmq.ROUTER)  # ROUTER
frontend.bind("tcp://*:5555") # For clients
backend.bind("tcp://*:5556")  # For workers

poll_workers = zmq.Poller()
poll_workers.register(backend, zmq.POLLIN)

poll_both = zmq.Poller()
poll_both.register(frontend, zmq.POLLIN)
poll_both.register(backend, zmq.POLLIN)

workers = WorkerQueue()

heartbeat_at = time.time() + HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL

while True:
    if len(workers.queue) > 0:
        poller = poll_both
    else:
        poller = poll_workers

    socks = dict(poller.poll(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL * 1000))

    # Handle worker activity on backend
    if socks.get(backend) == zmq.POLLIN:
        # Use worker address for LRU routing
        frames = backend.recv_multipart()
        if not frames:
            break

        address = frames[0]
        workers.ready(Worker(address))

        # Validate control message, or return reply to client
        msg = frames[1:]
        if len(msg) == 1:
            if msg[0] not in (PPP_READY, PPP_HEARTBEAT):
                print "E: Invalid message from worker: %s" % msg
        else:
            print ("sending: %s"%msg)
            frontend.send_multipart(msg)

        # Send heartbeats to idle workers if it's time
        if time.time() >= heartbeat_at:
            for worker in workers.queue:
                msg = [worker, PPP_HEARTBEAT]
                backend.send_multipart(msg)
            heartbeat_at = time.time() + HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL

    if socks.get(frontend) == zmq.POLLIN:
        frames = frontend.recv_multipart()
        print ("client frames: %s" % frames)
        if not frames:
            break

        frames.insert(0, workers.next())
        backend.send_multipart(frames)

    workers.purge()
```

**`Worker.py`**

```
from random import randint
import time

import zmq

HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS = 3
HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL = 1
INTERVAL_INIT = 1
INTERVAL_MAX = 32

#  Paranoid Pirate Protocol constants
PPP_READY = "PPP_READY"      # Signals worker is ready
PPP_HEARTBEAT = "PPP_HEARTBEAT"  # Signals worker heartbeat

def worker_socket(context, poller):
    """Helper function that returns a new configured socket
       connected to the Paranoid Pirate queue"""
    worker = context.socket(zmq.DEALER) # DEALER
    identity = "%04X-%04X" % (randint(0, 0x10000), randint(0, 0x10000))
    worker.setsockopt(zmq.IDENTITY, identity)
    poller.register(worker, zmq.POLLIN)
    worker.connect("tcp://localhost:5556")
    worker.send(PPP_READY)
    return worker

context = zmq.Context(1)
poller = zmq.Poller()

liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
interval = INTERVAL_INIT

heartbeat_at = time.time() + HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL

worker = worker_socket(context, poller)
cycles = 0
while True:
    socks = dict(poller.poll(HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL * 1000))

    # Handle worker activity on backend
    if socks.get(worker) == zmq.POLLIN:
        #  Get message
        #  - 3-part envelope + content -> request
        #  - 1-part HEARTBEAT -> heartbeat
        frames = worker.recv_multipart()
        if not frames:
            break # Interrupted

        if len(frames) == 3:
            print "I: Normal reply: ", frames
            liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
            time.sleep(4)  # Do some heavy work
            worker.send_multipart(frames)
        elif len(frames) == 1 and frames[0] == PPP_HEARTBEAT:
           # print "I: Queue heartbeat"
            liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
        else:
            print "E: Invalid message: %s" % frames
        interval = INTERVAL_INIT
    else:
        liveness -= 1
        if liveness == 0:
            print "W: Heartbeat failure, can't reach queue"
            print ("W: Reconnecting in")
            time.sleep(interval)

            if interval < INTERVAL_MAX:
                interval *= 2
            poller.unregister(worker)
            worker.setsockopt(zmq.LINGER, 0)
            worker.close()
            worker = worker_socket(context, poller)
            liveness = HEARTBEAT_LIVENESS
    if time.time() > heartbeat_at:
        heartbeat_at = time.time() + HEARTBEAT_INTERVAL
        #print "I: Worker heartbeat"
        worker.send(PPP_HEARTBEAT)
```

Answer (score 0):

### Add a HeartBeat signalling to the Control Layer

**If there is the only**

> *(cit.:)* "**problem** I'm seeing is that when the **broker goes down** (becomes unavailable), the client is unable to tell that the broker is unavailable and it continues to send requests."

simply add a trivial signalling ( be it of a `PUB/SUB` or other archetype ) that may keep just the last signalled timestamped presence with newer API using `.setsockopt( zmq.CONFLATE )` or have some even more robust, bilateral handshaking, that permits the sender to acquire a reasonable assumption right upon its will to send a next message to the consumer process, that all interested parties are fit and in such a state, that allows to reach the target functionality.

ZeroMQ is a great in this very sense, to help integrate both the smart-signalling and message-handling services into something like a fully-distributed Finite-State-Automata, or a network of statefully cooperating FSA-s, if one wishes to, a truly remarkable step into heterogeneous distributed systems ( queues being some non-core, additional means for doing this smart, fast and in a scaleable manner ).

One may soon realise the sort of additional risks of distributed mutual locking, that have to be incorporated into the professional system designs and validations. This new sort of issues may and does appear both in a naive use-case with `REQ/REP` across error-prone delivery of messages and, in more complex ways, in more complex distributed signalling/messaging FSA networks.